# Confusion in textFileStream

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I am using textFileStream for ingesting data into Spark Streaming. But the data is being processed only for one batch. My first question is that Does it not stream each and every record from the file.?

According to https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/rdd-streaming/debugging-streaming-applications.html `For TextFileStream, since files are input, the # of input events is always 0. In such cases, you can look at the “Completed Batches” section in the notebook to figure out how to find more information.`

Secondly, I would like to know how many records are being processed by Spark Engine.For example, If I stream a file of 1GB contanining 100K data records, I would like to know how much Spark Streaming took to execute it.

Can anyone please share their thought or some useful link. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Spark Version: 2.0.1
Data Ingestion from Amazon s3 via textFileStream

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to see this, But you can implement this using custom code.

For example, when you process the dStream generated by the textFileStream you use

```
    dStream.forEachRDD{rdd => rdd.forEachPartition{part => { }} }
```

So you can simply add some code inside rdd.forEachPartition {} block which will update no of records processed in either accumulator or add that info in a Kafka topic or add that information in zookeeper or even update a mysql database :)

```
dStream.forEachRDD{rdd => rdd.forEachPartition{part => {
            var recordProcessed:Int = 0; ...
            part.foreach{...;recordProcessed+=1}
            //update recordProcessed in kafka/HBase/Mysql/Zookepeer
    }} }
```

Which can be further used to visualize no of records process using  visualization tools.